# How to make Twilio custom view eager loaded?

Tags: twilio

In Twilio Flex UI plugin, here is how I created a custom view:
You can find the doc here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/custom-views-and-routes#configuration-options

```
import React from "react";
import * as Flex from "@twilio/flex-ui";
import { FlexPlugin } from "@twilio/flex-plugin";

import CustomTaskList from "./components/CustomTaskList/CustomTaskList";
import { View1 } from "./views/View1";
import { View2 } from "./views/View2";
const PLUGIN_NAME = "ViewRoutePlugin";

export default class ViewRoutePlugin extends FlexPlugin {
  constructor() {
    super(PLUGIN_NAME);
  }

  async init(flex: typeof Flex, manager: Flex.Manager): Promise<void> {

    Flex.ViewCollection.Content.add(
      <Flex.View name="my-custom-page" key="my-custom-page-key">
        <div>My custom page</div>
      </Flex.View>
    );

  }
}
```

When this view is loading, it shows loading screen, and it is lazy  loaded(load when it is accessed, e.g.: https://flex.twilio.com/my-custom-page/), taking 1 second,
Here is the loading screen:

[image]

but the default view has no loading screen, eager loaded, takes 0.1 second to switch, no loading screen when switching with left nav bar.

My question is:
How to make my above custom view loaded just like default view? no loading screen, eager loaded.